# Using Drag-Sort ListView with SQLite DB

Tags: drag-and-drop, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, listactivity, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a simple to-do-list app with an SQLite DB and a [Drag-Sort ListView](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview).

Right now I am binding data from an SQLite database cursor into a ListView using a SimpleCursorAdapter and adding items with an EditText view as explained in this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex1.html).

I have moved everything into one activity and I have swapped the plain ListView with a Drag-Sort ListView. My issue is connecting the DB and Drag-Sort ListView together. The DLSV demos use a predefined array to fill fill the DSLV.

Snippet form DSLV:

```
    DragSortListView lv = (DragSortListView) getListView(); 
    lv.setDropListener(onDrop);
    lv.setRemoveListener(onRemove);

    array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.jazz_artist_names);
    list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item1, R.id.text1, list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Snippet from my existing code:

```
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    ...
    mDbHelper.createNote(noteName, "");
    fillData();

    private void fillData() {
  // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
  Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
  startManagingCursor(c);

  String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
  int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

   // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
   SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
     new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
     setListAdapter(notes);
   }
```

Thank you and sorry if this doesn't make all that much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a github project available at https://github.com/jmmcreynolds/dslv-db-demo

This demo includes a working example of how to setup a DragSortListView that will save the changes that you make to the list (position, add/delete) to a database.

I have used it just now.  Its perfect demo project available for using DSLV with SQLiteDB.

Thanks to github user jmmcreynolds.

Answer (score 3):

Since you cannot reorder the items in a Cursor, you have to create a mapping between Cursor positions and ListView positions. This is done for you by the [DragSortCursorAdapter](http://bauerca.github.com/drag-sort-listview/reference/com/mobeta/android/dslv/DragSortCursorAdapter.html) class and subclasses so that the drag and drop reordering is maintained visually. If you need the new orders persisted (like to your database), then you must implement that logic yourself. The method [getCursorPositions()](http://bauerca.github.com/drag-sort-listview/reference/com/mobeta/android/dslv/DragSortCursorAdapter.html#getCursorPositions%28%29) will help you with this.

Comment: Admittedly, I have not gone back to this so I have not confirmed your answer. But I greatly appreciate the reply and believe this info does indeed answer the question. I will comment again if I have any clarifying questions.

Answer (score 3):

I have made use of Drag sort list view. Its amazing! but instead of using the dragsortcursoradapter i created my own trick. here it is.

What i have done is that whenever i swapped any item, i passed the new swapped list in an array to the database, deleted the table and recreated the new updated table. here is my code
here is the code snippet from my database handler

```
public void onUpdateToDoTable(ArrayList<Task> taskList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKTODO);
    String CREATE_TASK_TODO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_TASKTODO + "(" + SEQ_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + TASK_NAME + " TEXT )";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TASK_TODO_TABLE);
    for (int i = 0; i < taskList.size(); i++) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TASK_NAME, taskList.get(i).getTask());
        db.insert(TABLE_TASKTODO, null, values);
    }
    db.close();
}
```

then on using drop listener
i called the above method..

```
private DragSortListView.DropListener onDrop = new DragSortListView.DropListener() {
    @Override
    public void drop(int from, int to) {
        Task item = adapter.getItem(from);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter.remove(item);
        adapter.insert(item, to);
        db.onUpdateToDoTable(list);
        Log.d("LIST", db.getAllToDoTasks().toString());
    }
};
```

db is my object of database handler. whole source code is available at [dragdroplistview](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview). amazing example. this was a life saver for me. Ciao!